# How to save a vector object in android?

Tags: android, file, vector, save

I've been searching around a lot and couldn't accomplish this. I have created a class 'VectorEx', extending 'Vector', to store two methods, one for saving the vector and one for loading it. I know i have to use FileOutputStream and openFileInput() but I'm unable to create the file. I'm still pretty new to android programming, so a simple explanation is appreciated.

```
public class VectorEx extends Vector<Subject> {
public void save(String name, Context ctx) {
    try {
        File file = new File(name);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(this);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void load(String name, Context ctx) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput(name);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ois.readObject();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is the code I last tried using. From whatever I could understand of LogCat, it seems that this is a "Read-only file system".

Comment: Are you perhaps testing the code on a device that is connected to the PC as mass storage, and therefore the SD card is inaccessible? Anyway, this guide should provide what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: what is name?..Can you show us?

Comment: I have seen the Android Developer's Site a lot of times but I still don't know where I'm going wrong. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: what is name? print here

Comment: The 'name' variable I send when calling the method. I couldn't figure out a way to give a unique name to the save file using the name of the object calling the method, so instead I added a 'String' parameter to pass into the method to use to make the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of these permission is missing in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But I'm trying to save to the Internal Storage, not External SD. I will try this out though.

Comment: There's also a WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE, try both.

Answer (score 0):

```
here are the vector constucts:
Vector( ) 
Vector(int size) 
Vector(int size, int incr) 
Vector(Collection c)

//Demonstrate various Vector operations. 
import java.util.*; 
class VectorDemo { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        // initial size is 3, increment is 2 
        Vector v = new Vector(3, 2); 
        System.out.println("Initial size: " + v.size()); 
        System.out.println("Initial capacity: " + 
        v.capacity()); 

        v.addElement(new Integer(1)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(2)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(3)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(4)); 
        System.out.println("Capacity after four additions: " + 

        v.capacity()); 
        v.addElement(new Double(5.45)); 
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + 
        v.capacity()); 

        v.addElement(new Double(6.08)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(7)); 
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + 
        v.capacity()); 

        v.addElement(new Float(9.4)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(10)); 
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + 
        v.capacity()); 

        v.addElement(new Integer(11)); 
        v.addElement(new Integer(12)); 
        System.out.println("First element: " + 
        (Integer)v.firstElement()); 
        System.out.println("Last element: " + 
        (Integer)v.lastElement()); 

        if(v.contains(new Integer(3))) 
            System.out.println("Vector contains 3."); 
            // enumerate the elements in the vector. 
            Enumeration vEnum = v.elements(); 
            System.out.println("\\nElements in vector:"); 
            while(vEnum.hasMoreElements()) 
                System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement() + " "); 
                System.out.println(); 
            } 
        }
}



The output from this program is shown here:

Initial size: 0 
Initial capacity: 3 
Capacity after four additions: 5 
Current capacity: 5 
Current capacity: 7 
Current capacity: 9 
First element: 1 
Last element: 12 
Vector contains 3. 
Elements in vector: 
1 2 3 4 5.45 6.08 7 9.4 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure You're trying to write to the root directory. You probably want to be writing to your app's directory or External Storage(If any), not root.

Comment: Ah, I see. How can I change the directory for the file saving?