# Android Store a Vector<Vector<PointF>> in a file

Tags: android, graphics, vector

I draw a picture on Canvas and have its Path & 
    Vector of PointF objects.

I store all Vector in a Vector> variable.

When I try to store a object 
    Vector< Vector > of pointF

in a file, I get a IOException that it is Nonserializable since it is a android.graphics.pointf.

Do anyone have a suggestion on how I can store this data?

Comment: maybe this helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189192/how-to-save-a-vector-object-in-android)

Comment: Is there a way to store Vector<Vector<PointF>> ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use custom serialization. Just convert to a string that let's reconstruct the point. Saving X and Y with the required precision should be enough. For `Vector<Vector>>` (why are you using `Vector` at all?) you can use a simple text file (one `Vector` per line, etc.) or some structured format like JSON or XML. If you really want to use Java serialization, write a wrapper object and implement `read/writeObject()`.

Comment: I figured it can't be done and found a alternative method to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Of course it can be done. In any  case, add your solution as an answer and accept it. It might be useful to other people.